# Does being paragon or renegade in the previous games affect Mass Effect 3?

Tags: mass-effect-3

If my character's morality was heavily paragon or regenade in the previous two games, what will that affect in how Mass Effect 3 plays out? That is, does the morality of ME or ME2 change the story or gameplay in any noticeable way, or does Mass Effect 3 ignore that aspect of my imported character?

Comment: this question is not entirely a dupe, but can be answered by several other questions on this site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your morality scores don't play a role, but the decisions you've made in the previous games (i.e. the reason for your morality scores) do affect the game in a fairly major way.